# Fields in activity object cant be filled out with form/form handler

Tags: custom-object, tasks, activity, account-engagement

fields created in the activity object do not show up in pardot/webtolead as a custom field for my form handler (only fields created under lead show up in pardot/webtolead). So the field in activity is pointless if i cant fill it through a form or webtolead.

So how do i create a field in a pardot form that connects to a field created under activity object that can be used for task layout?